# Multiple Select into outfile

Tags: select, mysql-error-1064, heidisql, into-outfile

I m trying to run a query in HeidiSQL. If I run only one SELECT statement, everything works fine. If I want to run multiple SELECT statements I keep getting SQL error 1064

Any ideas what to change to the code?

SELECT id, date, customer_id
INTO OUTFILE 'orders.txt'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM orders;

SELECT order_id, line_number, quantity, discount, price
INTO OUTFILE 'order_line_items.txt'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM order_line_items;

Thanks!

Comment: Try moving the `FROM table` clause left: `SELECT ... FROM TABLE INTO OUTFILE...`. At least there seem to be server versions supporting only one of these variants.

Comment: Hi Anse,

thanks, this seems to work.

Although I get a warning message that it is deprecated and wil be removed in a future release, and please use SELECT INTO FROM instead.....

Comment: Ok, so we're back to the initial question, why two of such queries produce an error while one of them does not. By the way, on my MariaDB 10.3 these batch works, in both versions. So which server version is it on your side?

Comment: MariaDB 10.5.4
HeidiSQL 11.0.0.5919

Comment: Ok, HeidiSQL 11.1 is out since a few days. You could update and retry. The update may fix something due to an updated libmysql/libmariadb from the installer.